# How to add keyboard shortcuts to nemo?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, file-browser

I want to add gloobus to nemo in linux mint. But native support is not available therefore I want to add a keyboard shortcut to nemo to open gloobus with selected element.
I already found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333088/customize-nemo-keyboard-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-13-04#answers) where is described how to change shortcuts and I found [this](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=118713#p752869) where is described how to add an action to the context-menu.

Does anybody know how to add KEYBOARD shortcuts to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for Nemo 2.2.4 under Linux Mint 17 I do this:

- Go to: **/home/yourusername/.gnome2/accels** --- NOTE: .gnome2 is a hidden folder!
- Open the "nemo" file with your text editor
- Add your shortcut: for example, **when having 2 panes to move a folder or file from one pane to the other using "CTRL+j"**:

**(gtk_accel_path "/DirViewActions/Move to next pane" "j")**

```
Note: remove the ";" at the beginning of the line
```

- **Restart the GTK system**: sudo killall -u yourusername
- Open Nemo, to test my example: press "F3" choose different folders on each pane, select one folder or file from one pane and press "Ctrl+j", that folder or file should move from one pane to the other one.

There are a lot of different commands to customize in that file, be careful not to use a current shortcut!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not very up to date any more. [See here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417947/1082472) for how to do it in 2022.